# Converting DI signal to analog to record from an amp

Tags: audio-recording, dac

My idea is to record "clean" electric guitar and electric bass signals directly my Focusrite Scarlett 6i6, going into Ableton Live. Then I can edit the signal and piece together different takes to get the complete audio track I want.

After I have those tracks finished, I was wondering if there's a way to send an instrument-level signal from my DAW into my pedal board, running into my Fender guitar amp or Ampeg bass amp, which would give me the desired tone when mic'ed up. Can this be done with some kind of digital-to-analog converter?

My reason for wanting this is that I need a mic recording of a cranked amp, with the classic tube break-up, but my living situation doesn't allow me to crank an Ampeg SVT and record 15 different takes. This method would allow me to crank my amp and get the perfect take on the first try, before the neighbors finish dialing the police to make a noise complaint.

Comment: I'd look at 'soft' amps - VSTs - Guitar Rig, Amplitude, etc, or something like a Line6 DAC with built-in modelling.

Comment: I already use Guitar Rig 5 in Ableton. It's good, but it doesn't compare to my nice analog pedals and amps.

Comment: I'd say "it does, for this scenario" ;) Bear in mind, only you will ever know it wasn't real. You can even get some guitar/speaker feedback if you ramp the compressor on the take - even if you're only recording the clean signal. Recording both clean & amped would be ideal, if you've the drive space; but even without both, re-amping the output 'live' through Guitar Rig will still work for a comped set of takes.

Comment: The VST just seems "thin" to me. I try dialing in the mids and bass but I've grown so accustomed to the unique tone from my particular amps and mics that I think anything besides a Kemper Profiler would leave me unsatisfied.

Comment: Of course, it's not going to be perfect, but I've done entire albums on a Rockman before now & no-one ever complained;) (80s, admittedly)

Answer (score 1):

I have great news for you! What you are trying to do (re-amping) is actually very common in the recording world, and there are boxes specifically designed for this purpose. Radial makes a great re-amping box (ProRMP). here are some links with more information

http://www.radialeng.com/prormp.php

https://www.puremix.net/blog/how-to-reamp-getting-out-of-the-box.html

[image]

Comment: Thanks! My interface doesn't have XLR out, so will I lose signal integrity by using a 1/4" to XLR cable from y interface to the Reamp?

Comment: @PatrickShambayati on the 6i6 you should be able to use one of the balanced Line Outputs (3-4) for this task. You'll need a balanced jack to XLR cable to connect it up. I do this myself, and it sounds great!

Comment: Simon is correct. As long as your Scarlett's output is a balanced line out, it doesn't matter whether it's an XLR out or a 1/4". Just make sure you use a balanced 1/4" to XLR cable (the 1/4 side should be TRS). Here's an article explaining http://shure.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/650/~/how-do-i-wire-an-xlr-to-1%2F4-adapter-cable%3F